# Can Jaxb handle type attributes in Xml Schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Just modified my Xml Schema from

```
.......
<xs:element name="mood1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> 
<xs:element name="mood2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

to

```
..........  
<xs:complexType name="category">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
     <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
   </xs:sequence>`enter code here`
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="mood1" type="category"/>
 <xs:element name="mood2" type="category"/>
 ...........
```

to simplify it.

But now when I use JAXB (2.2.5) to generate Java classes for the schema it complains

```
 src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'category' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1741)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1433)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:630)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:616)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:574)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:540)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:101)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:357)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.loadModel(RawXJC2Mojo.java:630)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:258)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Cant jaxb handle the type attribute ?

Just updated to **JAXB 2.2.11** but made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it can.

You're using `category` without any prefix. For this to work, make sure that you have `xmlns="..."` matching the `targetNamespace` of your schema.

Feel free to post your full schema for us to check.

Comment: Ah yes you are quite right I need ed to specify name when i referernce the complex type from the element, now works thankyou.